# Generate number by using Dynamic array (w/o VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays, excel-365

I would like to generate a number from the raw data based on Name in `A1#` and check with `B1#` and `C1#` for each row until the maximum value of `D1#`. Each rows must be filled with 0 to the limit **D** , which case is **C** greater than **D** do not add 0.

All **raw data** are ****Array****

I use Excel 365

[image: Example image]

Can anyone help?

I trired to use  `SEQUENCE` and `INDEX` but I need its in Dynamic array form

Comment: I'm confused with the results for C. Shouldn't it just be '1-1' as per my answer below? The limit is set at '1'. If you allow '1-2' then the '6-6' for the last value for A does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JvdV commented I'm confused about A 6-8 being changed into 6-6, whereas with C 1-2 is kept unchanged.

This answer changes the end up to the limit value of it would exceed that:

```
=LET(r,   A2:D8,
     n,   INDEX(r,,1),
     s,   INDEX(r,,2),
     e,   INDEX(r,,3),
     l,   INDEX(r,,4),
     u,   UNIQUE(n),
HSTACK(  u,
         DROP(
              IFERROR(
                      REDUCE( 0,  u,
                      LAMBDA( bs, br,
                      VSTACK(
                             bs,
                             LET(start, FILTER(s,n=br),
                                 end,   FILTER(e,n=br),
                                 limit, XLOOKUP(br,n,l),                           
                             XLOOKUP(                          
                                     SEQUENCE(1,limit),                       
                                     end,                              
                                     start & "-" & IF(end>limit,limit,end),                                 
                                     0,                                 
                                     1)
                      )))),
                      ""),
               1)))
```

[image]

*Edit based on comment showing start and end regardless limit being greater than end value:*

```
=LET(r,   A2:D8,
     n,   INDEX(r,,1),
     s,   INDEX(r,,2),
     e,   INDEX(r,,3),
     l,   INDEX(r,,4),
     u,   UNIQUE(n),
HSTACK(  u,
         DROP(
              IFERROR(
                      REDUCE( 0,  u,
                      LAMBDA( bs, br,
                      VSTACK(
                             bs,
                             LET(start, FILTER(s,n=br),
                                 end,   FILTER(e,n=br),
                                 limit, XLOOKUP(br,n,l),                           
                             XLOOKUP(                          
                                     SEQUENCE(1,limit),                       
                                     end,                              
                                     start & "-" & end,                                 
                                     0,                                 
                                     1)
                      )))),
                      ""),
               1)))
```

Comment: I mean if Start = 1 , End = 2 and Limit = 1 then it should send 1-2. Limit like number of column of each row but I want to send Start and End only (1-2). Is it possible?

Comment: Just replace `start & "-" & IF(end>limit,limit,end)` with `start & "-" & end`

Comment: If I want Repeat this pattern for 3 time but last pattern send 0 only Example `F5` {D,1-2,1-2,0,1-2,1-2,0,0,0,0} What should i do?

Comment: I have the logic that if the end number exceeds the limit, it returns `0`. So `1-2` can be in the first and second column only. What logic would you use if you want to have it returned in the 3rd column as well? The logic of switching from one value to the next is gone then as well.

Comment: If the end value for `D` would be `3` it would be repeated 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=IFERROR(REDUCE(HSTACK("Name",SEQUENCE(,MAX(D2#))),UNIQUE(A2#),LAMBDA(a,b,LET(c,BYROW(HSTACK(C2#,D2#),LAMBDA(d,MIN(d))),e,FILTER(HSTACK(B2#,B2#&"-"&c,D2#),A2#=b),VSTACK(a,HSTACK(b,XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(,MAX(DROP(e,,2)))-1,TAKE(e,,1),INDEX(e,,2),0,1)))))),"")
```

If you really happen to have 4 dynamic arrays as input with headers, then maybe 'drop' those:

```
=IFERROR(REDUCE(HSTACK("Name",SEQUENCE(,MAX(DROP(D1#,1)))),UNIQUE(DROP(A1#,1)),LAMBDA(a,b,LET(c,BYROW(HSTACK(DROP(C1#,1),DROP(D1#,1)),LAMBDA(d,MIN(d))),e,FILTER(HSTACK(DROP(B1#,1),DROP(B1#,1)&"-"&c,DROP(D1#,1)),DROP(A1#,1)=b),VSTACK(a,HSTACK(b,XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(,MAX(DROP(e,,2)))-1,TAKE(e,,1),INDEX(e,,2),0,1)))))),"")
```

But best to ditch these prior in your original formulae.